# Printing a hex list actually prints a str list Python

Tags: python, string, list, hex

I have the following:

```
list = ['C1', '50', '40']
newlist = ["0x" + item for item in list]
newlist2 = [hex(int(item, 16)) for item in newlist]
print(newlist2)
```

However the output is ['0xc1', '0x50', '0x40']. Which makes no sense to me.. Why is it still a str list

Additionally, when try

```
print([0xc1, 0x50, 0x40])
```

It prints out [193, 80, 64], which is the int conversion of the hex

Can anyone explain what is happening here..Seems like I am missing something.. Why would making a hex list give me a str list? When I try hex(int(item, 16)) for each individual items, I actually get the correct hex conversion, but putting everything in a list seems to break it

Tried doing all the above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question does not make sense, because **there is no such thing as "a hex list"**. "hex" **isn't a type of data**, and there is **no such thing as** "a hexadecimal number", or "a binary number", "decimal number" etc. Just like there is no such thing as an English-words number, or an Arabic-digit-symbols number, or a Roman-numerals number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I get what mislieads you.
When list of strings is printed, then you can see `''` wrapping each element. This is ommited when string is printed alone, but it is still a string.

```
list = ['C1', '50', '40']
newlist = ["0x" + item for item in list]
newlist2 = [hex(int(item, 16)) for item in newlist]
print(newlist2)
print([isinstance(item, str) for item in newlist2])
print (newlist2[0])
print(isinstance(newlist2[0], str))
```

the output is this:

```
['0xc1', '0x50', '0x40']
[True, True, True]
0xc1
True
```